# Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = "list"; desired type = AbstractList; given type = List;

Tags: ios, core-data

I have been struggling with this stupid error for a full day now! As the error shows, it rejects the assignment because the "given type" is different than the desired type. This is wrong since AbstractList is a parent entity for List! I tried the following:

- Re-generation of all core data entities classes from the model.
- Casting to AbstractList (which sounds silly but the error is stupid and vague in the first place!).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I made a mistake when creating the core data stack. I am using a singleton to manage core data with an interface that supports CRUD operations. The bug was simply creating a new stack everytime I perform an operation! Yes, it's a stupid mistake same as the stupid error. I better go now and write my tests to make sure this class is robust enough.